# Best way to load CSS file based on JS variable Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What would be the proper way to do this in Vue?

```
const brand = 'op';

switch(brand)
{
    case 'ed':
        <style lang="sass" src="./ed.css"></style>
    break;
    case 'op':
        <style lang="sass" src="./op.css"></style>
    break;
    case 'go':
        <style lang="sass" src="./go.css"></style>
    break;
}
```

I have the style tags in the Vue app but I know I can't use the switch in that part other than the script tags.

Comment: The style tag does not accept a `src` attribute. You probably want a `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Vue way to do that. `<style>` tags do not take `src` attributes. `<link>` tags go [only in the `<head>` section](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp), and Vue operates on the `<body>`.

If you have single file components, and your css files are specific to them, you could make a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad) that defines the component functionality, and have three components that all use the mixin, but each has its own style. Then you could use a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to switch between them based on `brand`.

Comment: Thanks for the anser Roy J. I think I can do what I have in mind with Mixins.